# PostgreSQL 9.4 Very Slow Query

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm experiencing a very long response time for a query returning a relatively small number of rows. It takes over three minutes to return ~1.3 million rows. I would assume it was an indexing problem except counting the rows takes almost no time at all.

Amazon AWS: It's running on an RDS t2.medium with a SSD (IOPS disabled) according to AWS console.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ip_range_domains (
  ip_range_domain_id     BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  domain_id              BIGINT REFERENCES domains                        NOT NULL,
  source_type_id         INTEGER REFERENCES source_types                  NOT NULL,
  low                    INET                                             NOT NULL,
  high                   INET                                             NOT NULL,
  auto_high_conf         BOOLEAN                                          NOT NULL   DEFAULT FALSE,
  invalidation_reason_id INTEGER REFERENCES invalidation_reasons                     DEFAULT NULL,
  invalidated_at         TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE                                 DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE                      NOT NULL   DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
CREATE INDEX domain_id_btree ON ip_range_domains (domain_id);
```

I also created a hash index on it afterwards but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The slow Query

```
SELECT * FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266;
```

The query above took 224.9 Seconds

```
=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266;
  count  
---------
 1383530
(1 row)
```

The query above took 164 milliseconds to return.

```
=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_range_domains;
  count   
----------
 23156869
(1 row)
```

The query above took 1.9 seconds to complete.

```
=> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266;
                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on ip_range_domains  (cost=26398.17..282905.77 rows=1410288 width=55) (actual time=94.046..476.018 rows=1383530 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (domain_id = 400266)
   Heap Blocks: exact=44000
   Buffers: shared hit=47783
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_index_9  (cost=0.00..26045.60 rows=1410288 width=0) (actual time=85.699..85.699 rows=1383530 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (domain_id = 400266)
         Buffers: shared hit=3783
 Planning time: 0.122 ms
 Execution time: 697.753 ms
(9 rows)
```

Postgres Version:

```
=> select version();
                                                    version                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

RDS Info:

```
db.t2.medium
IOPS: disabled
```

Comment: why is `domain_id` not unique? is `(domain_id, source_type_id)` maybe a candidate key? Is a domain/host allowed to be multi-homed?

Comment: @wildplasser Yes. One of many examples would be your website is hosted on a CDN. You're renting the IP from the CDN (as are many others). It can get tangled and difficult to tell who's IP is who's.

Comment: Maybe you should check how you are retrieving rows?

Your EXPLAIN ANALYZE, which also executes the explained query, took 697.753 ms, so I'm thinking you may be fetching one row at a time?

Comment: @hruske How do I check? What's the solution?

Comment: 1.3 million rows * approximated row size is about 100Mb to transferring...

Comment: Since when 1.3 milion is relatively small?

Comment: You should check in the documentation of the client library you are using.
Eg. for Python's psycopg2 library, you would use fetchmany(1000) instead of fetchone() -- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone

Comment: @hruske I did that fetch using the psql command line tool.

Comment: @Abelisto Yeah, I guess it's not that small. Still, it's RDS in the same region as the server. That should take way less than three minutes.

Comment: IMO you have a data modelling problem. Your table should be decomposed into three or even more tables (The created_at, invalidated_at suggests a history, ...) You should ask yourself the question: what does the existence of a record in this table *mean* ? (and: what would it mean when another record with similar values for *some* of the columns would exist?)

Comment: @wildplasser With the exception of the invalid / valid which is purposely breaking normal form for unrelated reasons and the high/low range which isn't using proper notation, my data model is fine. This is only a question about the query speed and how to improve it. I don't think my data model has anything to do that. Currently those two columns are all null.

Comment: Then: how do you disallow overlapping ip-ranges. Over time... ?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266 LIMIT 1000;` for example. If it will works fine, then the problem not in query but in data amount. IMO you should to ask yourself for the reason to transfer so much data from server to client. And then you should to revisit your application logic.